# Gmail mobile stretches images

Tags: html, gmail, html-table, fluid-layout, email-client

I am trying to create a newsletter template in fluid design. The issue is a header image which gets stretched vertically when received and viewed in Gmail mobile and in some other minor clients. The solution by defining min-height and max-height in the table isn't working and I am out of tricks.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; height:100%; width:100%;">
    
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
       <td style="background-color:#81BCCE;">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="600" bgcolor="#F3F3F3" style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
            
            
<center>            
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px; height: auto; max-height: 120px; min-height: 60px;" >      
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="testlink.html" target="_blank"><img src="https://bloodstonescifi.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/banner11-600-x-120.jpg" alt="Image" border="0" style="font-size: 20px; color: #000000; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%; max-width: 600px; min-width: 300px; height:auto; max-height: 120px; min-height: 60px;"></a>
            </td>        
        </tr>
    </table> 
    
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" >      
        <tr>
            <td>
                This is some text content!
            </td>        
        </tr>
    </table>     
    
</center>
    
    
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#81BCCE;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- END CONTENT AREA -->

</body>
</html>
```

The image used here is merely a spaceholder for the real image, but the dimenson of 600 x 120 is correct. The way it's coded here shows a stretched image in Gmail mobile.
Is there any trick or workaround to fix this?

EDIT:

True, if you test this, it DOES look correct. I will now replace the spaceholder with the actual image and then give feedback about the fixing for others to read with a similar issue.

EDIT:

The problem has been solved. It was because of my used sending system that added a fixed height and width to the image under certain conditions.

Comment: I just made a test and I don't see the image stretched, can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: It's good you told me that it worked for you; I am really thankful for your time and action! That way I was able to get an idea where the problem could've been. It was not the HTML itself - it was the used software.

Comment: No problem at all! :)